# How to change the href in a link by using a toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've created a pricing table which changes the amount by clicking on a toggle. Now I also need the value of the `href` attribute of the link underneath the table to be changed when clicking on the toggle. I've tried to figure it out with a separate JavaScript function, but can't get it to work. It should again change back to the original `href` when clicking again on the toggle.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("prijs-small");
  if (x.innerHTML === "€18") {
    x.innerHTML = "€13";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "€18";
  }
};

function mailaanpassing() {
  document.getElementById("aanvragen").href = "mailto:someone@someone.com";
  return false;
};
```

```css
#mybutton {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ster {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.totale-button {
  text-align: center;
}

#mybutton input {
  display: none;
}

#mybutton>label {
  display: flex;
}

.side {
  width: 50%;
  padding-inline: 0.15rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #012d5d;
}

#mybutton input:not(:checked)~.left {
  background-color: #35CB8C;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
}

#mybutton input:checked~.right {
  background-color: #35CB8C;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="totale-button">
  <div id='mybutton'>
    <label for='mybutton-checkbox'>
      <input type=checkbox id='mybutton-checkbox' onclick="myFunction(); mailaanpassing()">

      <div class='side left'>150 <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class='side right'>350 <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="ster"> * </div>
</div>

<div id="prijs-small">€18</div>
<a href="mailto:me@me.com" id="aanvragen"><button>aanvragen</button></a>
```

Comment: The console error is pointing out your typo.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm still very new to javascript

Comment: Open your browser's debugging tools and read the error on the development console.  (Which is shown directly in the UI in the above code snippet.)  *"Uncaught ReferenceError: mailaanpassing is not defined"*

Comment: Yes I saw that when running the snippet, but what does it mean? How would I be able to fix that?

Comment: `mailaanpassing` is not the same as `mailaanpasing` you named your function `mailaanpasing` but in your `onclick` you called it like `mailaanpassing` with double `ss`

Comment: @ECDJ: It means your code has no function called "mailaanpassing".  Honestly, I don't know how else to explain this.  "mailaanpassing" and "mailaanpasing" are two different names.  Because one is "mailaanpassing" and the other is "mailaanpasing".

Comment: OK, fixed it. But it still is not changing the href in the button? So something else is not right either?

Comment: are you trying to change the text of the button of the href address?

Comment: the href address

Comment: Your code works fine.  The `aanvragen` button gives an error in the console because of how SO snippets work, but if you inspect element, the href is changed fine.   If you want to put it back, then just do exactly the same as you have in the other code.

Comment: it is working according to the code you gave us after correcting the name of your function, however it changes only once tho, it doesn't go back to previous address once you toogle it back 
check it https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/crtjsxua/2/

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to reset the attribute value on subsequent clicks.
2. You don't really need two functions. I've combined them.
3. Don't call JavaScript from your markup. Use event listeners. It's better to keep your markup clean and your script intuitive.
4. A button inside a link (anchor element) is invalid HTML. If you want a link styled as a button, do that. Don't nest those elements.
5. Use `let` and `const` rather than `var` for better scoping and safety.
6. Use better ID values, function names, and variable names. They should be intuitive and semantic. Your future self will thank you, along with anyone else working with your code.
7. From an application design perspective, checking a price for a specific value isn't a good strategy. If the price changes your code breaks. Consider adding a class or using some other abstract means to check price.

```js
function updateEmailAddress() {
  const prijsEl = document.getElementById("prijs-small");
  const mailEl = document.getElementById("aanvragen");
  const emailAddress1 = "mailto:me@me.com";
  const emailAddress2 = "mailto:someone@someone.com";
  const keyPrice1 = "€13";
  const keyPrice2 = "€18";

  if (prijsEl.innerHTML === keyPrice2) {
    prijsEl.innerHTML = keyPrice1;
    mailEl.href = emailAddress2;
  } else {
    prijsEl.innerHTML = keyPrice2;
    mailEl.href = emailAddress1;
  }

  console.log(mailEl.href);
};

document.getElementById('mybutton-checkbox')
  .addEventListener('click', () => updateEmailAddress());
```

```css
#mybutton {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ster {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.totale-button {
  text-align: center;
}

#mybutton input {
  display: none;
}

#mybutton>label {
  display: flex;
}

.side {
  width: 50%;
  padding-inline: 0.15rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #012d5d;
}

#mybutton input:not(:checked)~.left {
  background-color: #35CB8C;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
}

#mybutton input:checked~.right {
  background-color: #35CB8C;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
}

.button-link {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.button-link:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="totale-button">
  <div id='mybutton'>
    <label for='mybutton-checkbox'>
      <input type=checkbox id='mybutton-checkbox'>

      <div class='side left'>150 <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class='side right'>350 <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="ster"> * </div>
</div>

<div id="prijs-small">€18</div>
<a href="mailto:me@me.com" id="aanvragen" class="button-link">aanvragen</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you want to switch the href in your button. To do so you can process like this :

**HTML :**

For the HTML part just remove the call to your function `mailaanpassing` that change the href. You can do that in your function `myFunction` during the `if/else` block.

```html
<input type=checkbox id='mybutton-checkbox' onclick="myFunction()">
```

**Javascript :**

For the Javascript change your `if/else` block to this.

```js
if (x.innerHTML === "€18") {
    x.innerHTML = "€13";
    document.getElementById("aanvragen").href="mailto:someone@someone.com";
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "€18";
    document.getElementById("aanvragen").href="mailto:me@me.com";
}
```

What it does is just change the href depending on what you click on your toggle.

But for good practice I would reccomend you to not use the string of the `prijs-small` element, but rather check the checkbox in your DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You should use the editor to put your code in a demo snippet so we can see the solution in action.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an action, use a button. Links go places…

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question.